# problem with an app on my phone 2

Tags: android

i have wrote an app getting rss feed from the website of my university.in the eclipse emulator the app runs with no problem and i can reed the rss.but as i transferred it to my mobile(samsung gti 9000) the screen freeze when i push the button for the rss news...also,if i go for the menu button of the phone and change dom to sax the phone pops out a message to force down...any idea?may my phone has a problem?please keep on mind that my phone works on greek language and the emulator on english,i dont know if this matter.. this is the error on logcat as i press the button(i have connected my devise to the pc):

12-10 20:09:37.187: INFO/ActivityManager(2235): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.example.unipi/.home } 12-10 20:09:37.206: INFO/AndroidNews(11130): ParserType=ANDROID_SAX 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.kospol.gr:80 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.kospol.gr:80 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.example.unipi.AndroidSaxFeedParser.parse(AndroidSaxFeedParser.java:55) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.example.unipi.home.loadFeed(home.java:75) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.example.unipi.home.onCreate(home.java:30) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.kospol.gr:80 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.example.unipi.BaseFeedParser.getInputStream(BaseFeedParser.java:32) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at com.example.unipi.AndroidSaxFeedParser.parse(AndroidSaxFeedParser.java:53) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): ... 15 more 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.kospol.gr:80 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1054) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:62) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807) 12-10 20:09:37.211: ERROR/AndroidNews(11130): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1051)

Comment: change hostname to host ip address, that should not give any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your phone can't resolve the host

```
Host is unresolved: www.kospol.gr:80
```

Do you have internet on your phone? Can you connect to the website in a browser?

Comment: yes i have internet,i m getting with wifi from my home and of course i can open a website...i dont know where is the problem with this samsung device...

Comment: i changed the language of my phone from greek to english and the application is running woth no problem.but i return to greek the a  stacks...what's going on?

Comment: change your hostname to host ip address, that should not give any problem.

Comment: @Mukunda, that's not even close to an acceptable solution in most cases.